# AutoCompleteBox not found in wpf toolkit using visual studio 2012

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

This is really a wanted feature, AutoCompleteBox (not AutoCompleteComboBox apparently).
However, visual studio 2012 cannot find the AutoCompleteBox control. But I have not tried in earlier version of vs, so it may not be a version matter.

I installed wpf toolkit, added those extensions to my WPF project:

- WPF Toolkit
- WPF Toolkit Design
- WPF Toolkit Input Design
- WPF Toolkit Input Visual Studio Design
- WPF Toolkit Layout
- WPF Toolkit Layout Visual Studio Design
- WPF Toolkit Visual Studio Design.

Looks almost like virii to me. Every permutation of words are used...
Well well in my WPF project, I added

`xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"`

to a window and tried to also add a auto complete box like this:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox />
```

but AutoCompleteBox does not seem to exist, the first component that is listed when I have typed

```
<toolkit:
```

is ButtonBaseBehavior.

Comment: The following references need for the toolkit: `WPFToolkit.dll, System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit.dll, System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit.dll`. So you need to reference the `System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit` dll for the AutoComplateBox

Comment: Thanks for the answer! ButtonBaseBehavior is still the first listed class that I can use so there is something I have not done to make it work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not all the toolkit controls are included in the "main" namepace.

Let me explain it how are the toolkit dlls are built up:

You can also install the WPF toolkit through NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package WPFToolkit
```

It will add three dlls to your project:

- **WPFToolkit.dll** this contains the core/stable controls of toolkit which can be found in the `xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"`
- **System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit.dll**  this dll contains the *preview* controls like `AutoCompleteBox` and `Rating`
- **System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit.dll** this dll contains the *preview* layout controls like the `Accordion`

The *preview* controlls are not included in the main xmls namespace so you need to use a the namespace form the corresponding preview dll:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"

<controls:AutoCompleteBox />
```

Comment: I get `Install-Package : Unable to find package 'WPFToolkit'` error

Comment: The package has been renamed to Extended.Wpf.Toolkit https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/

Comment: Actually, I've found https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFToolkit/3.5.50211.1 and it says *"Please use the XCeed version of the toolkit: Extended.Wpf.Toolkit."* as you. However, I didn't find AutoCompleteBox control in https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit. This link has given in the description.

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to (Included in WPFToolkit):
    **`System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit.dll`**
and then in your xaml at the top:

```
xmlns:System_Windows_Controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
```

and for using it anywhere in your code just like this:

```
<System_Windows_Controls:AutoCompleteBox />
```

Comment: just a short answer for anyone that wants a quick reply!